# Get next element in td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span data-....></span></td> // 1
        <td><a href="">....</a><td>
        <td><span data-....></span></td> // 2
        <td><a href="">....</a><td>
        <td><span data-....></span></td> // 3
        <td><a href="">....</a><td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When i click on the span, how do i find the next span?

The span transforms in a input, when i press the TAB button i want to go to the next span...

Between every span there is a a href.. Without the a hrefs it work

```
$('table td span').hover(function () {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});

$(document).on('keydown', 'table td input', function(event) {
    var target = $(this);

    if (event.which == 9) {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log('Tab pressed');

        var span = target.parent().next().find('span');

        span.click();

        console.log(span.data('date'));
    }
});
```

Comment: $(this).parent().next()

Comment: I tried ```var span = target.parent().next('td').find('span');``` does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('table td').on('click', 'span', function(event) {
    $(this).parent()         // the parent of the span
           .next()           // the next element to that parent (href td)
           .next()           // the next element to that next element (span td)
           .find('span');    // the span children of the first
});
```

Comment: The `.first()` call is unnecessary

Comment: @Yooouuri please explain more! The code snippett in the example is working just fine!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir oke it works, but there is a a href between every span, see updated question

Comment: @Yooouuri see the **Edit** above!

Comment: @Yooouuri And you thought that is not important for us to know! See the new answer it should work unless there is more you haven't tell us about!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir my bad, forgot an didnt notice there was a a href, it works now, thanks!